# Optimised EmEditor Macro to return Min/Max column lengths on large delimited data

Tags: performance, emeditor

I currently have large delimited data sets and I need to return the min\max lengths for each column.
I'm currently using the following code in Emeditor v20.3, which works great, but am wondering if there is a quicker way, particularly when there are million of lines of data and hundreds of columns (and this code is slow).

Any quicker approaches or ideas would that could be wrapped into a javascript macro would be much appreciated.

```
for( col = colStart; col <= MaxCol; col++ ) {
    sTitle = document.GetCell( 1, col, eeCellIncludeNone );
    min = -1;
    max = 0;
    for( line = document.HeadingLines + 1; line < MaxLines; line++ ) {
        str = document.GetCell( line, col, eeCellIncludeQuotesAndDelimiter );
        if( min == -1 || min > str.length ) {
            min = str.length;
        }
        if( max < str.length ) {
            max = str.length;
        }
    }
    OutputBar.writeln( col + min + "    " + max + " " + sTitle);
}
```

Comment: You can use the **Find Longest Line/Cell** command and the **Find Non-Empty Shortest Line/Cell** command to optimize for the speed.

Comment: That's great. As shortest returns non-empty, is there an optimal way to check when/if min length = 0 via macro?

Comment: If the shortest cell length was not zero, then you can search for an empty cell. One way to do is search for `^$` (regex) within the selected column while the `'^' and '$' can Match Beginning and End of the Selection` option is set.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Yutaka, I was thinking something like this but I'll do some testing. If in a future version a method could be added to just return the Shortest (including zero), that would be great.


`var noZeroLengthData = document.Filter("",xOrgCell,eeFindWholeString,0,0,0);`

Comment: The next version (20.3.906) will include the **Find Shortest Line/Cell** command.

Comment: Great - thanks Yutaka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update EmEditor to 20.3.906 or later, and run this macro:

```
colStart = 1;
MaxCol = document.GetColumns();
document.selection.EndOfDocument();
yLastLine = document.selection.GetActivePointY( eePosCellLogical );

min = -1;
max = 0;
for( col = colStart; col <= MaxCol; col++ ) {
    sTitle = document.GetCell( 1, col, eeCellIncludeNone );
    document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosCellLogical, col, 1 );
    
    editor.ExecuteCommandByID( 4064 );  // Find Empty or Shortest Cell
    y = document.selection.GetActivePointY( eePosCellLogical );
    if( y < yLastLine ) {  // check if not the last empty line
        str = document.GetCell( y, col, eeCellIncludeQuotes );
        min = str.length;
    }
    else {  // if the last empty line
        document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosCellLogical, col, 1 );
        editor.ExecuteCommandByID( 4050 );  // Find Non-empty Shortest Cell
        y = document.selection.GetActivePointY( eePosCellLogical );
        str = document.GetCell( y, col, eeCellIncludeQuotes );
        min = str.length;
    }
    
    document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosCellLogical, col, 1 );
    editor.ExecuteCommandByID( 4049 );  // Find Longest Cell
    y = document.selection.GetActivePointY( eePosCellLogical );
    str = document.GetCell( y, col, eeCellIncludeQuotes );
    max = str.length;
    OutputBar.writeln( col + " : " + min + "    " + max + " " + sTitle);
}
```

Comment: Excellent - works as expected and much quicker (hopefully in future versions, it may be able to run quicker still). Thank you Yutaka!